# Dynamically lazy load react components in vite via string path

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have the current code to create a list of available `View` components within a certain file. (The view component is just a regular component but it has the work View at the end of it). The user selects the views to load and then these should be lazy/dynamically imported and available

```
const loadViews = () => {
  const paths = import.meta.glob(`./views/*.*`, { eager: true });
  const matchingPattern = /\/views\/(.+?View).tsx/;
  const viewMap = Object.keys(paths).reduce((acc: any, current: any) => {
    const match = current.match(matchingPattern);
    return match ? acc.set(match[1], match[0]) : acc;
  }, new Map());

  return viewMap;
};
```

Now I have a mapping of component name to component path.

In theory I want to use import.meta.glob with `{eager: true}` but vite does not support using variables in this case. Is there another way I can do this?